# Site statistics and conduct

Tags: discussion

Just wondering if it is alarming that questions and answers are not being upvote (or even downvote) much despite of increase in the user base (which is now grown to over 1000) and increase in visitors/day (over 800 per day).

Also, can we encourage community to accept the answer if it resolve their issue by somehow.

Can we do something in this regard or is it something we do not have much control on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, we've always seemed to have the same ratio (or even quantity) of active participants even on the old forum. What's great about today is it's no longer the same participants. It seems we have new names, more clients, and more non-technical participants and questions than just a few years ago.

Though I've seen active campaigning through Tweets, Meta posts like this, and personal emails work to increase participation, nothing seems as effective as showing someone how Tridion Stack Exchange works.

So I'm not alarmed since it'll always be a challenge for any community to encourage participation. Knowing a few of the participants personally, I would suggest our strongest  *fascination trigger* are prestige, vice, and maybe power.

Consider ideas like:

- Tweets, contests, or other campaigns to answer unanswered questions
- Comments recognizing and thanking good behavior
- Poking fun of bad forum behavior (probably from other sites rather than this one, or doing so internally without embarrassing participants)
- Face-to-face and direct, friendly requests and reminders seem very effective

*Once this participation becomes part of someone's online identity, then it's hard to make them stop participating.* :-)

Answer (score 6):

To be honest I have found that - compared to other SE sites - the rate of voting is quite high here. I've also found voters here tend to be quite generous in their judgments.

The thing to remember here is that the vast majority of those 800 visitors/day are going to be passive readers. That's not a bad thing. In fact, it's in-line with one of the key goals of StackExchange; to produce a useful, searchable Q&A resource where people can find repeatable answers to existing questions. Active asking and answering isn't the only (or even primary) use case of the site.

That's what makes the model work so well. If you need to ask, you can ask and you will get an answer. Ideally, though, you won't need to ask because the answer is already there.

Regarding accept rates, all you can do is drop in a comment prompting the user to accept the answer if it solved the problem. The user's accept rate used to be displayed in the question itself but [it was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) as it has the potential to discourage people from posting valuable answers.

Comment: In terms of us being "quite generous," are we *too* nice, Ant? :-)